# How are JavaScript libraries saved by the browser?

Tags: javascript

I use a library on my main site `www.domain.com` as such

```
<script src = 'lib.js'>
```

However, when I link out to another tab that points to ( using `target = '_blank'` )

```
www.domain.com/path
```

the library is gone and I have to reload it.

Is this expected behavior?

I thought because resources like `localStroage` have limits based on domain that other aspects of the `environment` would be domain based.

That is resources I load at `www.domain.com` I thought would be available at `www.domain.com/path`.

But this seems to not be the case.

Comment: What do you mean by saying that "the library is gone"? It must be downloaded again by the browser? It must be referenced again in your HTML file (using `script` tag)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Javascript files are only loaded for one page and need to be loaded again for every other page regardless of the domain or path.

Comment: what is said above is correct.. your browser may cache the file so it don't have to be downloaded twice but you have to link it to every page you want it on. otherwise you would have a lot of scripts that conflict with each other..

Comment: what gezzuzz says and also as a security measure